# Winning Streak per player per event MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have tried the different solutions with the "winning streak" search criteria, but I can't seen to fit them in my situation.

I have the following tables:

BetHistory:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
|   id  | betid | betstatus |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| 63281 | 63280 | lose      |
| 63280 | 63279 | won       |
| 63279 | 63278 | lose      |
| 63278 | 63277 | lose      |
| 63276 | 63275 | won       |
| 63275 | 63274 | won       |
| 63271 | 63270 | won       |
| 63270 | 63269 | won       |
| 63269 | 63268 | won       |
| 63268 | 63267 | won       |
| 63267 | 63266 | lose      |
| 63266 | 63265 | won       |
| 63264 | 63263 | won       |
| 63262 | 63261 | won       |
| 63261 | 63260 | lose      |
| 63259 | 63258 | lose      |
| 63258 | 63257 | won       |
| 63257 | 63256 | lose      |
| 63256 | 63255 | lose      |
| 63254 | 63253 | won       |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Bets:

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| betid | gameid | username |
+-------+--------+----------+
| 63280 |   7506 | player1  |
| 63279 |   7506 | player2  |
| 63278 |   7506 | player5  |
| 63277 |   7506 | player2  |
| 63275 |   7506 | player12 |
| 63274 |   7506 | player12 |
| 63270 |   7506 | player5  |
| 63269 |   7505 | player2  |
| 63268 |   7505 | player12 |
| 63267 |   7505 | player2  |
| 63266 |   7505 | player5  |
| 63265 |   7505 | player1  |
| 63263 |   7505 | player2  |
| 63261 |   7504 | player2  |
| 63260 |   7504 | player5  |
| 63258 |   7504 | player5  |
| 63257 |   7504 | player2  |
| 63256 |   7504 | player2  |
| 63255 |   7503 | player2  |
| 63253 |   7503 | player1  |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

EventGames: - another table that stores relation between games and events, which could easily be integrated, as needed.

I need help in framing the MySQL statement to determine the players that have at least five (5) straight wins.

Much thanks in advance.

**Edit**: the table below may be easier:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+------+
| id    | betstatus | gameid | username | team |
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+------+
| 63281 | lose      |   7506 | player12 | C    |
| 63280 | won       |   7506 | player7  | A    |
| 63279 | lose      |   7506 | player3  | B    |
| 63278 | lose      |   7506 | player10 | B    |
| 63276 | won       |   7506 | player1  | A    |
| 63275 | won       |   7506 | player1  | A    |
| 63271 | won       |   7506 | player3  | A    |
| 63270 | won       |   7505 | player7  | B    |
| 63269 | won       |   7505 | player1  | B    |
| 63268 | won       |   7505 | player10 | B    |
| 63267 | lose      |   7505 | player3  | A    |
| 63266 | won       |   7505 | player12 | B    |
| 63264 | won       |   7505 | player10 | B    |
| 63262 | won       |   7504 | player10 | B    |
| 63261 | lose      |   7504 | player3  | A    |
| 63259 | lose      |   7504 | player3  | A    |
| 63258 | won       |   7504 | player10 | B    |
| 63257 | lose      |   7504 | player7  | A    |
| 63256 | lose      |   7503 | player7  | A    |
| 63254 | won       |   7503 | player12 | B    |
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+------+
```

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data

Comment: It could be easier but, each instance of the bets can have different status. Bets table can also accommodate for teams, but the above can probably suffice.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the link, I've been there and I was not successful at adopting it because of the difference in data structure.

Comment: What is the purpose of having `id` and `betid` columns for `BetHistory` table? Why do you need `betid`?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko, thanks for the notice, the structure was coarsely produced, hence the edit. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables to get the desired result:

```
SELECT username, MAX(streak) AS streak
FROM (
  SELECT username, betstatus, id,
         @streak := IF(betstatus = 'lose', IF(@uid := username, 0, 0),
                      IF(@uid = username, @streak + 1,
                         IF(@uid := username, 1, 1))) AS streak

  FROM (
    SELECT b.username, bh.betstatus, bh.id
    FROM Bets AS b
    INNER JOIN BetHistory AS bh ON b.betid = bh.betid) AS t 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @streak := 0, @uid := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY username, id) AS s
WHERE streak >= 5  
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY username
```

**Note:** I have used the original table structure.

**Note 2**: The query uses *nested* `IF` expressions to properly initialize and access variables.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3954af/4)

Comment: Looks like it works that way, I'll give it a try and push it even further. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sql is applied to united table which is named `BetHistory` from your **Edit**. The idea used is taken from @Matt's comment.

```
select Distinct(t.username)
from
    (select bh1.username, bh1.id, count(bh2.id) as streakGroup 
    from BetHistory bh1
    left join BetHistory bh2
    on bh1.id < bh2.id and bh1.username = bh2.username and bh1.betstatus <> bh2.betstatus
    where bh1.betstatus = 'won'
    group by bh1.id, bh1.username) as t
group by t.streakGroup, t.username
having Count(t.id) >= 5
```

**[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23454/1)**. `team` and `gameid` columns are omitted as they are not used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the answers posted, and I thank you all for the bright ideas.

Complex as it is to check for streaks, I opted to just add an listener that whenever a game announced the winner, winning sides's streak are incremented and the losers will start with 0.

I then can just simply query the table with the streak condition.

Much thanks,